# Get a single string from a LINQ to XML query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

Here is what I want to do:

```
string parseCode = from x in xml.Descendants("LogType")
                   where x.Attribute("ID").Value == string)ddlHistoryLogDefinitions.SelectedValue
                   select x.Attribute("ParseCode").Value;
```

But that gives error: *"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string'"*

There will only be one value for `x.Attribute("ParseCode")` but it insists on returning type `IEnumerable<string>`. How can I extract that value into a string ?

EDIT: Thank you for your responses. Here is what worked for me:

```
string parseCode = (from x in xml.Descendants("LogType")
                    where x.Attribute("ID").Value == (string) ddlHistoryLogDefinitions.SelectedValue
                    select (string) x.Attribute("ParseCode").Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

This trick was wrapping the entire linq query in () before the .FirstOrDefault().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.Single` to select the only result if you know there will be one and only one:

```
string parseCode = (from x in xml.Descendants("LogType")
                   where x.Attribute("ID").Value == string)ddlHistoryLogDefinitions.SelectedValue
                   select x.Attribute("ParseCode").Value).Single();
```

Use `.SingleOrDefault` or `.First` If there might be none or more then one respectively.

Comment: You need parentheses around the query expression.

Answer (score 1):

You query returns a collection. If you need the first found `LogType` node, then you can do something like this:

```
string parseCode = xml.Descendants("LogType")
    .Where(x => x.Attribute("ID").Value == (string)ddlHistoryLogDefinitions.SelectedValue)
    .Select(arg => x.Attribute("ParseCode").Value)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Will return `null` if no element found.